# ExtJS 4.1.x - Picker with a Combobox inside

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

I have a custom picker class with some text fields and a combobox inside. A grid in the app is using this picker as an editor for a column, but the problem is that anytime I click the combobox, the picker loses it's focus and closes. Is there a way to modify the picker in order to use the combobox for select data?

Comment: If possible, please share the code

Comment: use "CD"s workaround, http://jsfiddle.net/8E85C/

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this issue by using the `collapseIf` function.

This code checks if the event target is a `BoundList` (internally used `DataView` for `ComboBox`) and part of the picker component:

```
collapseIf: Ext.Function.createInterceptor(Ext.form.field.Picker.prototype.collapseIf, function (e) {
        var boundList = Ext.get(e.target).up('.x-boundlist'),
            cmp;

        cmp = boundList && Ext.getCmp(boundList.id);

        if (cmp && this.picker.down('#' + cmp.pickerField.id)){
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Comment: There is a mousedown handler attached to a function called "mimicBlur" that also hides the picker inside "triggerBlur". so i think its wanted to add your workaround to both mimicBlur and collapseIf methods.

Comment: Refer to this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?243946-Pickerfield-s-picker-ignores-collapseIf-when-used-in-grid-editor